# How can i detect CODEC in MPMoviePlayerController in iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

When Video is made with the Sorenson CODEC... MPMoviePlayerController just plays Audio(and not the Video), Instead i want to show my custom error message at this point. How can i detect which CODEC is used by particular File programmatically ... ?

EDIT: I am not using Quick time in my code so that solution won't work

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this documentation to understand the Quicktime file format : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/qtff.pdf

The field you are looking for is the "vfmt" code that is containing the video fourcc code (there is one for each video track in your file, so take care if your file is containing several video tracks). The fourcc codes for Sorenson codec are "SVQ1" and "SVQ3".

Now you'll have to write some code to parse the QT file to find the correct atom, extract the "vfmt" value and compare it to SVQ1/SVQ3 !

Apple is providing some classes to easily parse quicktime files, but it is only available on Mac OS, not on iOS !

Comment: Thanks, but it will work with QuickTIme and not MPMoviePlayerController how can we do the same in MPMoviePlayerController with iOS

Comment: MP4 files are using the same format (quicktime atoms) than quicktime files ! MPMoviePlayerController will not tell you that the codec is unsupported if there is an audio track it can play ! You'll have to do it out of the MPMoviePlayerController. If your are trying to play a local file, just write a quicktime atom parser and before playing the video, just parse the video file to check that the fourcc code is ok ! If you are streaming a file, then you should write a stream parser (it may add important delay before the video could play then ...).